# Смысловая необходиость написанного когда

Tags: c++17

Мне надоели Сишные функции и стараюсь делать свои "плюсовые", например

```
strncpy ( _text, str, TEXT_SIZE);
```

у меня получилось заменить на

```
using v_vec = std::vector<const char*>;
using q_vec = std::unique_ptr<v_vec>;
//====================================
v_vec className{};
v_vec winName{};
//-----------------------------    
className.push_back("Winnie") ;
winName.push_back("Hello Windows!");
//-----------------------------
className.back();
winName.back();
```

Хотелось бы услышать мнение профессионалов.

Comment: не понятно, что именно у вас получилось то?

Comment: в принципе я заменил функцию копирования строк на вектор она еще и вызывает ошибку в "студии"

Comment: ну раз вы с++ и stl используете, то чем вас тогда std::string не устраивает?

Comment: под Win32 API возникают проблемы совместимости

Comment: @WladWlad какие именно проблемы?

Comment: требует совместить STRING с CHAR или с CONST CHAR*

Comment: а код можете привести и вы `<string.h>` не забываете подключать?

Comment: так STRING,.H и есть Сишный

Comment: Наверное имелось ввиду ```#include <string>``` для C++

Comment: В плюсах CONST CHAR* вот я и создаю вектор этого типа - работает без проблем.

Comment: Все равно не понятна проблема. В "плюсах" точно так же можно создать `vector<string>`. Приведите пример проблемы, которую решает ваш набор функций, но не решается уже существующими средствами - тем же `std::string`.

Comment: Проблема с API она не понимает плюсового стринга.

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает [это](https://pastebin.com/0Lav3G3F) создание строки из ```const char*```?

Comment: Для преобразования ```std::string``` в ```const char*``` ознакомьтесь с [этим](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

Comment: Меня то устраивает Win API не устраивает.

Comment: ```stdStr.c_str()``` вернет вам ваш ```const char*```, что конкретно не работает и зачем такие извраты как в вопросе?

Comment: У меня есть допустим идентификатор кнопки в файле ресурсов и его нужно передать в окно. Сишная функция просто копирует строку, но вызывает ошибку "небезопасная функция, Нет смысла сначала переводит в стринг, а потом обратно.

Comment: @WladWlad метод `c_str()` не переводит "обратно", а просто возвращает указатель на буфер внутри объекта.

Comment: вот и вопрос в том, что проще создавать буфер или создавать вектор

Comment: С вектором, по крайней мере, не нужно следить за переполнением.

Comment: @WladWlad в string не нужно следить за переполнением. Буфер не нужно никакой создавать.

Comment: Я переделал это в шаблон ```template<typename T>
T copyMy(T t)
{
  std::vector<T> vec{};

  vec.push_back(t);

  return vec.back();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Я переделал это в шаблон:

```
template<typename T>
T copyMy(T t)
{
  std::vector<T> vec{};

  vec.push_back(t);

  return vec.back();
}
```

Comment: Не понимаю, чем вы занимаетесь. Так и не привели здравого примера, где бы ```std::string``` уступал вашим костылям, но продолжаете их составлять

Comment: Вообще то я занимаюсь экспериментами. Я могу заставить работать и сишные функции, но интересно же как можно сделать по-другому Вот шаблонный вариант мне самому понравился.

Comment: Вы когда на велопрогулку едете, тоже сначала велосипед изобретаете (конструктор копирования класса string)?

Comment: А как можно изобрести луноход если не изобретать велосипед? Кстати, их и сейчас изобретают. И не думаю, что библиотечные функции лучше своих - они рассчитана на "все и сразу". А вот моим шаблоном можно копировать все что угодно и без лишних затрат той же памяти. У меня много таких утилиток для локального использования.

Comment: Как говорится, слепому не покажешь... :)